# _MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS causes compiler errors in GCC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, sse, intrinsics

I'm compiling my math library in GCC instead of MSVC for the first time and going through all the little errors, and I've hit one that simply makes no sense:

`Line 284: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment`

What's on line 284? this:

`_MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS(r, u, t, _mm_setr_ps(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));`

(r, u, and t are all instances of `__m128`)

Those familiar with using `xmmintrin.h` will be aware that `_MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS` isn't actually a function, but rather a macro, which expands to:

```
/* Transpose the 4x4 matrix composed of row[0-3].  */
#define _MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS(row0, row1, row2, row3)           \
do {                                    \
  __v4sf __r0 = (row0), __r1 = (row1), __r2 = (row2), __r3 = (row3);    \
  __v4sf __t0 = __builtin_ia32_unpcklps (__r0, __r1);           \
  __v4sf __t1 = __builtin_ia32_unpcklps (__r2, __r3);           \
  __v4sf __t2 = __builtin_ia32_unpckhps (__r0, __r1);           \
  __v4sf __t3 = __builtin_ia32_unpckhps (__r2, __r3);           \
  (row0) = __builtin_ia32_movlhps (__t0, __t1);             \
  (row1) = __builtin_ia32_movhlps (__t1, __t0);             \
  (row2) = __builtin_ia32_movlhps (__t2, __t3);             \
  (row3) = __builtin_ia32_movhlps (__t3, __t2);             \
} while (0)
```

So...  what's causing my compiler errors?  I don't redefine anything here, that I know of.  This exact same code compiled and ran perfectly well when I was using MSVC.

Comment: Clearly `_mm_setr_ps(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)` does not expand to an lvalue.

Comment: Is this C or C++ code?

Comment: The code snippet is C++.

Comment: I added the visual-c++ and intrinsics tag to your question. This is really a problem with MSVC and not with GCC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change:

```
_MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS(r, u, t, _mm_setr_ps(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
```

to:

```
__m128 v = _mm_setr_ps(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
_MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS(r, u, t, v);
```

since this is an in-place transpose, and the 4 input vectors are also used for output.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it.  Why did it let me do this in MSVC but not in GCC?

Comment: Are the definitions of `_MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS` the same for both compilers ?

Comment: It is using the intrinsic directly. GCC defines `_mm_unpacklo_ps` as an inline function that calls `__builtin_ia32_unpackps`. If it used `_mm_unpacklo_ps` in in this macro your code would fail for the same reason.

Comment: @RossRidge, yeah, I see that now. The problem is in MSVC. It compiles and runs `_mm_setr_ps(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) = _mm_shuffle_ps(tmp2,tmp3, 0XDD);` just fine.

Comment: @PaulR, my first answer really stunk, I'm surprised I did not get down-voted for it. But anyway, I updated my answer with the assembly output from MSVC. I'm not sure what it's doing but it's clearly not storing the result in the row.

Answer (score 2):

MSVC uses its own definition:

```
#define _MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS(row0, row1, row2, row3) {                 \
            __m128 tmp3, tmp2, tmp1, tmp0;                          \
                                                                    \
            tmp0   = _mm_shuffle_ps((row0), (row1), 0x44);          \
            tmp2   = _mm_shuffle_ps((row0), (row1), 0xEE);          \
            tmp1   = _mm_shuffle_ps((row2), (row3), 0x44);          \
            tmp3   = _mm_shuffle_ps((row2), (row3), 0xEE);          \
                                                                    \
            (row0) = _mm_shuffle_ps(tmp0, tmp1, 0x88);              \
            (row1) = _mm_shuffle_ps(tmp0, tmp1, 0xDD);              \
            (row2) = _mm_shuffle_ps(tmp2, tmp3, 0x88);              \
            (row3) = _mm_shuffle_ps(tmp2, tmp3, 0xDD);              \
        }
```

The last line is getting converted to `_mm_setr_ps(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) = _mm_shuffle_ps(tmp2,tmp3, 0XDD);` which compiles just fine in MSVC but fails with the lvalue error in GCC. I'm not sure why MSVC allows this.

I looked at the assembly output of this code in MSVC2013

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{

    __m128 rows[4];
    //rows[0] = _mm_setr_ps( 1, 2, 3, 4);
    //rows[1] = _mm_setr_ps( 5, 6, 7, 8);
    rows[2] = _mm_setr_ps( 9,10,11,12);
    rows[3] = _mm_setr_ps(13,14,15,16);

    //_MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS(rows[0],rows[1],rows[2],rows[3]);
    //_MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS(rows[0],rows[1],rows[2],_mm_setr_ps(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    rows[2] = _mm_shuffle_ps(rows[2], rows[3], 0x88);
    _mm_setr_ps(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) = _mm_shuffle_ps(rows[2],rows[3], 0XDD);
}
```

Here is the relevant assembly code

```
; Line 14
    mov eax, 16
    imul    rax, 3
    mov ecx, 16
    imul    rcx, 2
    movups  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR rows$[rsp+rcx]
    shufps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR rows$[rsp+rax], 136   ; 00000088H
    movaps  XMMWORD PTR $T6[rsp], xmm0
    mov eax, 16
    imul    rax, 2
    movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR $T6[rsp]
    movups  XMMWORD PTR rows$[rsp+rax], xmm0
; Line 15
    mov eax, 16
    imul    rax, 3
    mov ecx, 16
    imul    rcx, 2
    movups  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR rows$[rsp+rcx]
    shufps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR rows$[rsp+rax], 221   ; 000000ddH
    movaps  XMMWORD PTR $T8[rsp], xmm0
    movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR __xmm@3f800000000000000000000000000000
    movaps  XMMWORD PTR $T7[rsp], xmm0
    movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR $T8[rsp]
    movaps  XMMWORD PTR $T7[rsp], xmm0
```

Comment: It's still not clear to me how setting the `row3` parameter to `_mm_setr_ps(...)` could ever work, given that it is assigned to in the last line of the macro ?

Comment: @PaulR, good point. But it should still compile even if it gives the wrong result (`_mm_setr_ps(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) = _mm_shuffle_ps(tmp2,tmp3, 0XDD)`). But I still wonder why GCC uses builtins that map to intrinsics instead of the intrinsic directly. I guess one reason would be to keep this kind of bug from happening?

Comment: No - I think gcc is perfectly correct to bail with `error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment` - `_mm_setr_ps(...)` is not an lvalue and trying to assign to it really is an error - I don't know how this gets past MSVC - maybe there's something funny about they way MS define `_mm_setr_ps` ?

Comment: @PaulR, right again. I did not think about his careful enough. Anyway, that's the clue `_mm_setr_ps(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) = _mm_shuffle_ps(tmp2,tmp3, 0XDD);` compiles fine in MSVC but gives the `lvalue` error in GCC. I'll look into this again tomorrow. I don't know why I care about MSVC anymore...