# Incorrect results when using SSE instrinsics in Visual Studio 2010/2012 and Release mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, sse

I'm computing the mean and variance of an array using SSE intrinsics. Basically, this is the summation of the values and its squares which can be illustrated in the following program:

```
int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    union u
    {
        __m128 m;
        float f[4];
    } x;

    // Allocate memory and initialize data: [1,2,3,...stSize+1]
    const size_t stSize = 1024;
    float *pData = (float*) _aligned_malloc(stSize*sizeof(float), 32);
    for ( size_t s = 0; s < stSize; ++s ) {
        pData[s] = s+1;
    }

    // Sum and sum of squares
    {
        // Accumlation using SSE intrinsics
        __m128 mEX = _mm_set_ps1(0.f);
        __m128 mEXX = _mm_set_ps1(0.f);
        for ( size_t s = 0; s < stSize; s+=4 ) 
        {
            __m128 m = _mm_load_ps(pData + s);      
            mEX = _mm_add_ps(mEX, m);
            mEXX = _mm_add_ps(mEXX, _mm_mul_ps(m,m));
        }

        // Final reduction
        x.m = mEX;
        double dEX = x.f[0] + x.f[1] + x.f[2] + x.f[3];
        x.m = mEXX;
        double dEXX = x.f[0] + x.f[1] + x.f[2] + x.f[3];

        std::cout << "Sum expected: " << (stSize * stSize + stSize) / 2 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "EX: " << dEX << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Sum of squares expected: " << 1.0/6.0 * stSize * (stSize + 1) * (2 * stSize + 1) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "EXX: " << dEXX << std::endl;
    }

    // Clean up
    _aligned_free(pData);
}
```

Now when I compile and run the program in Debug mode I get the following (and correct) output:

```
Sum expected: 524800
EX: 524800
Sum of squares expected: 3.58438e+008
EXX: 3.58438e+008
```

However, compiling and running the program in Release mode the following (and wrong) results are produced:

```
Sum expected: 524800
EX: 524800
Sum of squares expected: 3.58438e+008
EXX: 3.49272e+012
```

Changing the order of accumulation, i.e. EXX is updated before EX, the results are OK:

```
Sum expected: 524800
EX: 524800
Sum of squares expected: 3.58438e+008
EXX: 3.58438e+008
```

Looks like a 'counterproductive' compiler optimization or why is the order of execution relevant? Is this a known bug?

**EDIT:**
I just looked at the assembler output. Here is what I get (only the relevant parts).
For the release build with `/arch:AVX` compiler flag we have:

```
; 69   :    // Second test: sum and sum of squares
; 70   :    {
; 71   :        __m128 mEX = _mm_set_ps1(0.f);
vmovaps xmm1, XMMWORD PTR __xmm@0
mov ecx, 256                ; 00000100H

; 72   :        __m128 mEXX = _mm_set_ps1(0.f);
vmovaps xmm2, xmm1
npad    12
$LL3@main:

; 73   :        for ( size_t s = 0; s < stSize; s+=4 ) 
; 74   :        {
; 75   :            __m128 m = _mm_load_ps(pData + s);      
vmovaps xmm0, xmm1

; 76   :            mEX = _mm_add_ps(mEX, m);
vaddps  xmm1, xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rax]
add rax, 16

; 77   :            mEXX = _mm_add_ps(mEXX, _mm_mul_ps(m,m));
vmulps  xmm0, xmm0, xmm0
vaddps  xmm2, xmm0, xmm2
dec rcx
jne SHORT $LL3@main
```

This is clearly wrong as this (1) saves the accumulated EX result (`xmm1`) in `xmm0` (2) accumulates EX with the current value (`XMMWORD PTR [rax]`) and (3) accumulates in EXX (`xmm2`) the square of the accumulated EX result previously save in `xmm0`.

In contrast, the version without the `/arch:AVX` looks fine and as expected:

```
; 69   :    // Second test: sum and sum of squares
; 70   :    {
; 71   :        __m128 mEX = _mm_set_ps1(0.f);
movaps  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR __xmm@0
mov ecx, 256                ; 00000100H

; 72   :        __m128 mEXX = _mm_set_ps1(0.f);
movaps  xmm2, xmm1
npad    10
$LL3@main:

; 73   :        for ( size_t s = 0; s < stSize; s+=4 ) 
; 74   :        {
; 75   :            __m128 m = _mm_load_ps(pData + s);      
movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rax]
add rax, 16
dec rcx

; 76   :            mEX = _mm_add_ps(mEX, m);
addps   xmm1, xmm0

; 77   :            mEXX = _mm_add_ps(mEXX, _mm_mul_ps(m,m));
mulps   xmm0, xmm0
addps   xmm2, xmm0
jne SHORT $LL3@main
```

This really looks like a bug. Can anyone comfirm or refute this issue with a different compiler version? (I currently do not have permission to update the compiler)

Comment: It looks like a bug to me. I cannot reproduce your issue on version `16.00.40219.01 for 80x86` (MSVC2010), both in console and in devenv. You might try to install some service packs, perhaps it was fixed at some moment. Also, I may suggest using second union `y` instead of `x` to reduce `EXX`.

Comment: Try upgrading the compiler. MSVC has a history of miscompiling SSE/AVX intrinsics.

Comment: Did you compile in 64-bit mode? Visual Studio (the version I have used) default to 32-bit mode.

Comment: If you use `_mm_storeu_ps` instead of union what do you get?

Comment: Compiler version is `16.00.40219.01 for x64` (SP1). Using `_mm_storeu_ps` or using two separate unions does not help. I just found out that the issue arises if you set the `/arch:AVX` flag.

Comment: Good work! I wonder if the problem goes away using `_mm_loadu_ps`. In any case your code looks okay so far to me so it should not cause a problem. What intrinsic header are you compiling with? Are you using a SSE or AVX header when you comile with `/arch:AVX`?

Comment: Ok, now I can reproduce your issue on MSVC2010 in x64 mode with `/arch:AVX`, it is definitely a bug.
However, it does not appear in x86 mode. Also, it does not appear without `/arch:AVX`.
BTW, it does **not** reproduce on MSVC2013 (in x64 and with AVX). So perhaps it was fixed at some moment, who knows...

Comment: Thanks for your confirmations, good to know that this bug seems to be fixed with MSVC2013. @Zboson: Unaligned loads do not fix the problem. Neither does including SSE,SSE2 or AVX headers...

Comment: @jawa, thanks for checking this. This problem reminds me vaguely of [another bug I found in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25363538/2542702). Though in that case I would argue MSVC should *not* have compiled the code whereas in your case your code is perfectly fine code (except for the fact that using intrinsics invokes UB in many cases anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually performing the horizontal addition, I'd recommend using the corresponding SSE instruction `_mm_hadd_ps`

```
// Final reduction
__m128 sum1 = _mm_hadd_ps(mEX, mEXX); 
        // == {EX[0]+EX[1], EX[2]+EX[3],  EXX[0]+EXX[1], EXX[2]+EXX[3]}
// final sum and conversion to double:
__m128d sum2 = _mm_cvtps_pd(_mm_hadd_ps(sum1, sum1));
// result vector:
double dEX_EXX[2]; // (I don't know MSVC syntax for stack aligned arrays)
// store register to stack: (should be _mm_store_pd, if the array is aligned)
_mm_storeu_pd(dEX_EXX, sum2);
std::cout << "EX: " << dEX_EXX[0] << "\nEXX: " << dEX_EXX[1] << std::endl;
```

Comment: Note that this is actually an SSE3 instruction. This is very broadly supported (for gamers, Valve's Hardware survey puts it at 99%), but you need to explicitly check for support and have some way to communicate to the user that their system is too old if it doesn't. For more information on SSE3, see [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/09/11/directxmath-sse3-and-ssse3/). On modern PCs you can rely on SSE and SSE2 being universally supported--at least outside of emerging markets still running 12+ year old hardware--, but SSE3 isn't quite universal yet.